# Escape single quote in the input parameter in a Function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-11

I have a JSON which comes with single quote for one of the fields like below. A function with JSON as Input parameter is created and be called directly from the application. 
I would have used regexp_replace at least if it is read into the function.

for ex:

```
select '{
  "phrase": "foo",
  "phrase_1": "'bar'"
  }' :: json 

syntax error at or near "'"

  }'"
LINE 3:   "phrase_1": "'bar'"
```

The output of this is an error. so my actual problem is this json is directly read into my function.

```
create or replace function f_n(in json) -- it is failing to read here
returns text
---
---
end;
$$
```

so what is that I can do here to avoid such problem in postgresql?

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes need to be duplicate in SQL [to escape them](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS):

```
select '{
  "phrase": "foo",
  "phrase_1": "''bar''"
  }'::json;
```

alternatively use Postgres' [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) to avoid that:

```
select $j${
  "phrase": "foo",
  "phrase_1": "'bar'"
  }$j$::json;
```

When passing that as an argument to a function, this works the same:

```
select f_n('{
  "phrase": "foo",
  "phrase_1": "''bar''"
  }'::json);
```

or

```
select f_n($j${
      "phrase": "foo",
      "phrase_1": "'bar'"
      }$j$::json);
```